How to use regex in Java for complex strings
I am new to JAVA coding, and I am trying to learn how to use regex.
The input string:
String URL = "{Records=[{messageId=ac013823-100a-4b92-bb7a-a891b7b113d1, "
                + "receiptHandle=AQEBtDp6D3AVkifVlrM/No2dtCxxazqQOGjFcNrUO2t0JLS0awsBMEEwPfbdwrLyrO8ovneeAs3LIr30kPsx/T7NDP3mAOnYfPAMswHf4hQxQS2H7XCFc5ii/fCNai9FdaV+I/281MCHswfWYhoQII6e+alGmkPuwXPjBvQG6PDsFh9OF+/B05MBYP2uGR4mPoBfAJinDbabyZ7QaTEkgeATgvrHB7OmF0AJaJi/cN8bioZ2W+54bTi5HOJPF/oyCScGOYdTjtSDtvc1L+GP3qm2cC2m5XQ05ziCF3S7LUhjN6Go9EGkn1K1BLQPI/EbkIr8fGOzCmvl3NzE222pAArn2UxNCztSAerkpSfPTVAM72AOygXYXVWosmRMo4E7uT0H, body={\r\n"
                + "  \"tenant\": \"https://example.com,us-east-1-oe-stg-001-lc000chart,us-east-1\"\r\n"
                + "}, attributes={ApproximateReceiveCount=455, "
                + "SentTimestamp=1722503530891, SenderId=AIDAQKVRD5OEBZLPV7XNP, "
                + "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp=1722503535891}, messageAttributes={}, "
                + "md5OfBody=5a8e4022b9b9876a4c854e2a02d4c3b9, eventSource=aws:sqs, eventSourceARN=arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:022920031112:teq, "
                + "awsRegion=us-east-1}]}";

Now what I need is, entire line after the "tenant" string untill "us-east-1".
So basically this line:
"tenant\": \"https://example.com,us-east-1-oe-stg-001-lc000chart,us-east-1

So I wrote the regex like this:
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^tenant]+[0-9a-zA-Z]+(,[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // prints /{item}/
        } else {
            System.out.println("Match not found");
        }

But it is not working, not sure why. What am I doing wrong here?

Is there any reason why you aren't using a JSON parser for this?

just to start, [^tenant] means one character that is none of the listed ones, that is, any character that is not one of a, e, n or t -- if the input is supposed to be a JSON, better use a parser for it; otherwise you will have to eventually deal with line breaks (between key and value), quotes, ...

on the other side if you really want to do that with regular expression and you need the line, then you must use the MULTILINE mode of Pattern together with ^ and $ and maybe search for example for ^ *"tenant":.*$ (MULTILINE is a flag for compile(), or start the regular expression with (?m) )

It is better to deserialize string to JSON and get attribute. For example with jackson library. But you should generate valid json string, current string is not valid json string
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode tenant= jsonNode.get("body").get("tenant");

I dont recommend you to use regexp for this task, but here is an example of regexp you want
 String regex = "\"tenant\": \"([^\"]+)\"";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

 if (matcher.find()) {
     String tenantValue = matcher.group(1);
     System.out.println("Tenant value: " + tenantValue);
 }


@user2315104 but be aware, as already warned, that the regular expression solution may fail with some valid JSON. For example: white spaces, including line feeds, before/after the : (not a problem if the String is created by the code itself, not a JSON {based on previous question})
